# Securing Oracle External table data file

Tags: oracle

I've just learned one of Oracle features: External table. But when I use this external table in my application, I get a problem and wonder how to solve it.

The problem is: the security of the data file of external table (It's in text format).

How can I secure this data file effectively?

The target environment is: Red hat Linux enterprise 5.4; Oracle 10g.

Because of that environment, I cannot use Oracle DBFS to secure this file. Should I save the external data file in LOB data type in an independent database? Would you suggest me any other solution for my problem?

Comment: What are your security concerns, exactly?

Comment: My security concerns are exactly file security. In this situation, it's external table data file. Could you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure only the operating system user that starts the Oracle service/database (typically "oracle") can read the input files for the external services.

Then no other user will be able to mess around with them.

Comment: How can i guarantee for that? The external data file will be written by server module of an application and is selected by oracle pl/sql command.

Comment: @DzungNguyen: just make sure the default privileges on the directory are setup correctly

Comment: The privileges are setup by Java code or PL/SQL command? So how can i setup correctly in this case?